# getClientRects() from window.getSelection()

Tags: javascript, getselection, getclientrect

I've tried reading the official documentation, and I'm sure this is possible - I'm just struggling with how to do it.

How can I fetch the coordinates, width and height from some text that's been selected by the user? (By 'selected text', I mean text that's been highlighted with the mouse by the user)

Comment: `window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: When I JSON.stringify() I'm just getting an empty object. Any ideas?

Comment: props on `getBoundingClientRect` aren't enumerable. clone the object.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I'm getting somewhere with the following, `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects();`